# Reliable installer

Tags: installer, system-reliability

I have just brutally terminated Skype installer, which now gives me error 1603 whenever I try to restart the installaion. This brings be back to the issue that bothers me for a long time: how do you design a reliable installer? It must be reliable because it makes modifications to your system (as opposed to app that works in its sandbox) and upgrading the BIOS or installing an app must be reliable. I would even say "transactional": either your installation succeeds or nothing is changed. Leaving system in invalid state breaks its operation without easy way to repair. This topic should be severely researched therefore. Can you direct me to the literature or give brief overview of the principles, how reliable installer should work in principle and what is the state of the art in the industry?

Comment: Off topic and additionally - we are not a free research resource.

Comment: Not sure whether the “answer” should be a rant about Windows' arcane software distribution model or a link-only answer to [Guix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Guix)…

Comment: @5gon12eder So you are saying it is not possible to create installation script in Guix, that fucks up the system?

Comment: @Euphoric The goal is, at least, that if it does, you can roll back the misguided modification. I haven't used Guix personally, though, and cannot testify how well it works in practice.

Comment: @5gon12eder Single link is not enough. I followed it and could not understand what makes Gruix more reliable than other installers. It does not discuss the features of Grux at all, other than it is free license.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about research. This is about handling all the possible cases, like different OSes, HW, file systems, additional software (like antiviruses), installation requirements, etc.. Something that is neither practical, nor economically viable.

The "state of the industry" is like you said. Reliable installation is only for "app stores" with everyone giving up on making "reliable" installer on non-sandboxed environments.

About transactions : The problem is exactly same as above. The amount of actions installer can take is so big that it makes impractical. It not only copies files, but also changes registry, updates system files, updates user files, it can write anywhere on the disk, it can download files from internet and all kind of crazy things. The transaction system would have to support intallation, upgrade and uninstallation. There is also possibility that some other application's change might end up inside the transaction.

One more thing is that there exist some "standard" installers for most OSes. Windows has it's MSI. And it might do just what you want. If configured properly. But others might want to install their application in a way that makes MSI either not possible or would require non-standard configuration, possibly breaking the process.

Comment: Whilst I think the question is suboptimal, I like this answer. The number of different environments and their permutations is enormous. One must have an appetite for Sisyphian tasks before even considering it.

Comment: What is not practical? My question is not asking about research. It is asking about transactions. I have no idea about "state of the industry". I am asking about it.

Comment: You say that what I want is not practical but MSI (standard windows installer that is used most of the time) does exactly what I want. It copies files and modifies the registry. I am confused.

Comment: @valentin MSI does exactly what you want within the subset of functionalities supported by MSI, and if properly configured, and if the installer fails properly and is not killed mid-process. Designing a installer that works always, supports everything, and leaves your system in a good state under all possible situations is very much something that's not practical.

Comment: @lker How is that different from database? Why is it practical to make transactions in the database but not in the system upgrade and how would one make one? Why is it such bad/taboo-ed question?